# Laravel structure of table comments for guest and user

Tags: php, laravel

I need, when guest add comment, I need check email him. When he send comment, I need confirm email him, for it in table I have column email_token.

Now My comments table structure:

```
- id
- post_id
- user_id
- name
- email
- email_token
- email_verified_at
- body
- created_at
- updated_at
```

I have a question about structure of my table. How will be better? Do all columns for guest (name, email, email_token, email_verified_at) in comments table, or create separate table for guest comments? I need show all active comments in post model. If guest not confirmed email, then comment not active.

In post model I have this:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->whereNotNull('email_verified_at')->orWhereNotNull('user_id'); //display only comments by user and guest (with confirmed email)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate table for the guest users.

When a known user does comment on a post, you don't need the email verification, do you? So these fields would be unnecessary.

You could build a standard model, just for the guest user. Later you can expand the functionality by adding ways to convert guest users to normal users and keep their comments and so on. This would be way easier, with a separate table, than with your mixed.

To make things more efficient you could go the extra mile and make the users belonging to the comment [morphable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations). So it really easy to keep track of the users.